# Method for Syncing Page Load in Coded Ui

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have used playback. wait(3000) in my Coded Ui Script, to wait until my website it loaded. Sometimes the script fails, if the website takes more time to load. Is there any other way to wait until page is loaded ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for posting a question in a better way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Answer (score 1):

PlayBack.Wait() is simply a sleep statement, which would wait unconditionally for given number of time. For UI Sync you should consider using waitfor statements. Something like below,

```
// Set the playback to wait for all threads to finish  
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;

// Wait till your control is read (Loaded)
browserWindow.WaitForControlReady();

// Reset the playback to wait only for the UI thread to finish  
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
```

Take a look at [other wait statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg131072.aspx) as well to sync your app better.